# Sentinel 2 Tool Box on Commandline

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, sentinel-snap

Has anyone tried to use the Sentinel toolbox in command-line? I have downloaded the SNAP tool and installed on a Ubuntu workstation and the GUI works well. I now want to want to use it in a command-line so that I can automate some processes. Is there any documentation on how to get started with the SNAP tool on a command-line environment?

Answer (score 3):

SNAP contains tools to help you automate tasks: in the `Tools` menu you'll find entries for `GraphBuilder`  and `Batch Processing`.